# cor() standard deviation error is zero using random sample of data

Tags: r, caret

I'm reading a paper by Max Kuhn called [Building Predictive Models in R Using the caret Package](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper&ei=oj_IUK5FsMrQBdC-gcgF&usg=AFQjCNFNcBMI8dmK33j2Q1TPtmXLy4GUxA&bvm=bv.1354675689,d.d2k). He uses two data sets, `desc` and `mutagen`. Their content is not important here.

He runs the following code:

```
library("caret")
set.seed(1)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(mutagen, p=3/4, list=FALSE)
trainDescr <- descr[inTrain,]
descrCorr <- cor(trainDescr)
highCorr <- findCorrelation(descrCorr, 0.90)
trainDescr <- tranDescr[, -highCorr]
```

When I try to run `cor(trainDescr)`, I get the error

```
In cor(trainDescr) : the standard deviation is zero
```

followed with

```
Error in if (mean(x[i, -i]) > mean(x[-j, j])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

when running `findCorrelation()`.

If I try and run the code on the whole data set `descr`, and not the random sample, everything works fine. 
I'm running R version 4.12.1 on 32-bit ubuntu.

Hope this makes sense to someone.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package, but it would seem that there is some problem with `trainDescr`. Can you give us the output for `trainDescr`?

Comment: The content of `mutagen` *is* important to solve the problem.

Comment: trainDescr is a quite large data frame with 3252 rows and 1579 columns. 
I tried writing to .RData and .txt but both files are more than 10Mb.. Anything in particular you are interested in? Mutagen is a factor with the levels "mutagen" and "nonmutagen".

Comment: One note: You have a typo in set.seed() (you have an extra 'e'). If this is just a typo here, you can edit it. If you did that in R you can fix it there and here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion on this. There was a snippet of code left out of the script to remove "zero-variance predictors".

```
library(caret)
> library(caret)
> load(url("http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/descr.RData"))
> nrow(descr)
[1] 4335
> load(url("http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/mutagen.RData"))
> set.seed(1)
> inTrain <- createDataPartition(mutagen, p=3/4, list=FALSE)
> trainDescr <- descr[inTrain,]
> zv <- apply(trainDescr, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
> sum(zv)
[1] 3
> trainDescr <- trainDescr[, !zv]
> descrCorr <- cor(trainDescr)
> highCorr <- findCorrelation(descrCorr, 0.90)
> length(highCorr)
[1] 926
```

Max

Comment: Thank you.
Could I not instead use trainDescr <- trainDescr[,-nearZeroVar(trainDescr)] to remove zero variance predictors?
Again, thanks and happy holidays.